# Do we need all three tags "strings", "string-manipulation" and "text"?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Should [strings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strings) be a synonym of [text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text)? I think [string-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string-manipulation) has a good rationale for questions involving `StringReplace` and other transformations, but for processing, importing and exporting textual data in the form of a `String`, is there any real distinction between [text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text) and [strings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strings)?

And if there is, could someone please add it to the relevant tag-wikis? ([text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/text/info), [string-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/string-manipulation/info) and strings (to be created)).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Text should be a synonym of Strings or vice versa, as Text could also relate to the Text style in the FrontEnd which has (almost) nothing to do with the programmatic use of Strings.

Comment: but the usage of `text` is highly inconsistent, making it a "bad" tag. Although I agree with you that it shouldn't be a synonym, I guess the only way is to prevent its usage

Answer (score 3):

Following Sjoerd's argument, I would sugges the removal of [text](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text), as if it is understood as a style, the question should be tagged as [stylesheet](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet). If Text refers to a corpus, I would rather go for [string-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string-manipulation) (because any string would certainly involve *some* manipulation). If however Text refers to `Text` (the graphics primitive) then one can use [graphics](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics).

(If you think that there is a strong distinction between **using** strings and **manipulating** them, than we should keep both [strings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strings) and [string-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string-manipulation), but I would not know what to write in the wikis to make this difference clear).

Comment: I don't see what interesting things one could do with strings except for manipulating them.

Comment: Exactly my point, @celtschk :)

Answer (score 0):

One can store data in strings without necessarily performing manipulation of the string itself.  Strings may also be used as option names or `DownValues` keys.  These uses may warrant [strings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/strings) apart from [string-manipulation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/string-manipulation).